# How can I alter KWin rules via TTY?

Tags: kde, kde4, kde-neon

I'm quite new to Linux and managed to screw up my desktop (KDE) royally... I wanted to change my global window transparency and set it to 0% opacity, instead of 0% transparency, as I had intended.

I used the procedure described here: https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/Force_Transparency_And_Blur

Obviously, I cannot take the same route back, because all KDE setting windows ae fully transparent as well.

My idea is to remove the rule that I applied manually via TTY. However, I could not find it under `~\.kde4`. I also did a restore via timeshift, but that did not help. Apparently the rules are stored somewhere in `root` or `home`, because these directories are excluded from the snapshots.

Any help is greatly appreciated, because a fully transparent desktop quite impedes productivity.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to solve it by myself. Here is what I did:

The tutorial that I linked in the question mentioned the config key `opacityactive`.

I already knew, that the config file had to be somewhere in `~` or `/root`. So I started TTY with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> and went to both of these directories and issued `grep -rnw . -e 'opacityactive=100'`. And there it was: `~/.config/kwinrulesrc`

So I just edited the file with `nano ~/.config/kwinrulesrc` and changed

```
opacityactive=100
opacityinactive=100
```

to

```
opacityactive=0
opacityinactive=0
```

Finally, I rebooted the system with `sudo reboot`.